# Site collection with diferent url

Tags: 2010, site-collection, site

I have a question regarding the adress of the site collection.

I know the web application is sort of enterance point, which has ofcourse different urls, but is it possible to assing an url to site collection? Or should it always be the adress of web application + site collection?

For example:

- Site collection 1= www.sitecollection1.com
- Site collection 2 = www.sitecollection2.com
  ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Host Named Site Collections (HNSC) to create site collections with unique  URL's, e.g. http://sitecollection1.domain.com and http://sitecollection2.com;

This is a good resource on HNSC: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markarend/archive/2012/05/30/host-named-site-collections-hnsc-for-sharepoint-2010-architects.aspx

> Create a Host-Named Site Collection for every request for a site that
>   requires its own “vanity” URL. That these URLs can be either of the
>   format http://newsite.customer.com, or even http://www.newsite.com, as
>   far as SharePoint is concerned.
>
> - DNS must be configured to serve the
>     appropriate addresses.  If there are more than one web application in
>     the farm that contain Host-Named Site Collections, then it will
>     probably not be possible to use a wildcard DNS “A” record such as
>     *.customer.com to direct all traffic correctly, but each HNSC will need a separate DNS “A” record. See analysis of options for creating
>     multiple web apps, below.
> - This option is for a less frequent, more
>     “long-term” type of configuration request, justifying the additional
>     effort.